# JPA CriteriaBuilder for join in subquery

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

I have SQL statement something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM person inner join (select max(validityId) as maxID from person group by personId) maxID on maxID.maxID = person.validityid;
```

So it give me "distinct" row for personID:

If I have table like this :

```
|  personID  |  validitID | value   |
-------------------------------------------
|    1       |    10      | 400     |
|    1       |    11      | 500     |
|    1       |    12      | 600     |
|    2       |    13      | 700     |
|    2       |    14      | 800     |
|    2       |    15      | 900     |
|    4       |    16      | 1000    |
```

it would return

```
|  personID  |  validitID | value   |
-------------------------------------------
|    1       |    12      | 600     |
|    2       |    15      | 900     |
|    4       |    16      | 1000    |
```

Now I try to do this by JPA CriteriaBuilder.

My first thought was sub query :

```
final CriteriaBuilder cb = this.em.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<Person> cq = cb.createQuery(Person.class);
final Root<Person> root = cq.from(Person.class);
cq.select(root);

final Subquery<Long> subquery = cq.subquery(Long.class);
final Root<Person> validityIDSQ = subquery.from(Person.class);
subquery.select(validityIDSQ.get(Person_.validityId));
subquery.groupBy(validityIDSQ.get(Person_.personId));

cb.where(cb.in(root.get(Person_.validityId)).value(subquery));
```

But this produce error

```
 ERROR: column "person1_.validityid" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

How to this right?

Marko

Comment: You are not using an agreggation function in the subquery. It is not an JPA issue, even SQL fails for `select validityId from X group by personId`. Try `subquery.select(cb.sum(validityIDSQ.get(Person_.validityId)))`

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the solution is simpler than it seems. You forgot to include `cb.max ()` in the CriteriaBuilder subquery. The following code executes the query you are looking for.

```
final CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<Person> cq = cb.createQuery(Person.class);
final Root<Person> root = cq.from(Person.class);
cq.select(root);

final Subquery<Integer> subquery = cq.subquery(Integer.class);
final Root<Person> validityIDSQ = subquery.from(Person.class);
subquery.select(cb.max(validityIDSQ.get(Person_.validityID)));
subquery.groupBy(validityIDSQ.get(Person_.personID));

cq.where(cb.in(root.get(Person_.validityID)).value(subquery));
```

This code will create the following query:

```
select
    person0_.id as id1_0_,
    person0_.personID as personID2_0_,
    person0_.validityID as validity3_0_,
    person0_.value as value4_0_
from
    person person0_
where
    person0_.validityID in (
            select
                max(person1_.validityID)
            from
                person person1_
            group by
                person1_.personID)
```

I think you are using Postgres. Without `cd.max()` it generates the error you cited because you use the GroupBy without using an aggregate function. I tested it on Postgres and MySQL. Runs like a charm on both.