# Specific SQL to JPQL query convert

Tags: jpa, jpql

I am looking for the equivalent of this SQL query in JPQL

```
SELECT l.*
FROM product_update l
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            ID_PRODUCT,
            MAX(ID) AS maxID
        FROM product_update
        GROUP BY ID_PRODUCT
    ) groupel ON l.ID_PRODUCT = groupel.ID_PRODUCT
        AND l.ID = groupel.maxID
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

My java class

```
public class ProductUpdate extends BaseEntity {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PRODUCT_UPDATE_SEQUENCE")
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;

@JoinColumn(name = "ID_PRODUCT")
@ManyToOne()
private Product product;


@JoinColumn(name = "ID_VERSION")
@ManyToOne()
private Versioning versioning;
}
```

indeed, a product may have several versions, but the system just displays the product with the max (id)
Example:

```
1-Product 1 --- Version 1 
2-Product 2 --- Version 1
3-Product 3 --- Version 1
4-Product 1 --- Version 2
5-Product 3 --- Version 2
6-Product 3 --- Version 3
```

that the query just comes out

```
2-Product 2 --- Version 1
4-Product 1 --- Version 2
6-Product 3 --- Version 3
```

Thank.

Comment: Have you tried to make one yourself, or are you expecting someone here to do your work for you? Please show us your attempt.

Comment: Since JPQL is based around classes/fields and you haven't posted any classes, why not have a think what people are likely to contribute to that?!

Comment: and guess what ... you STILL HAVE NOT POSTED THE CLASSES (in your question!)

Comment: This what i have done `SELECT pu FROM ProductUpdate pu INNER JOIN ( SELECT pu.product, MAX(pu.id) AS maxid FROM ProductUpdate pu GROUP BY pu.product ) groupepu ON pu.product = groupepu.produit AND pu.id = groupepu.maxID ORDER BY pu.id DESC`.
But it shows me this warning on netbeans the joint association path is not a valid expression.
Here is my Table
`ProductUpdate 
(Id, Name
FK Product)`

Comment: ^ Please add your attempt in the question itself, using a formatted block.

Comment: I also change in this `SELECT pu FROM ProductUpdate pu INNER JOIN ( SELECT pu.ProductUpdate , MAX(pu.id) AS maxid FROM ProductUpdate pu GROUP BY pu.product.id ) groupepu ON pu.product.id = groupepu.produit.id AND pu.id = groupepu.maxID ORDER BY pu.id DESC`
And i get the same error `the joint association path is not a valid expression.`
Please some help

Comment: I finally got the good query, `select pu from ProductUpdate pu where pu.id in (select MAX(pUd.id) from ProductUpdate pUd group by pUd.product.id) ORDER BY pu.id DESC`. I just use this post  [JPA CriteriaBuilder for join in subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35148276/jpa-criteriabuilder-for-join-in-subquery) to perform my answer. 
1.Using a JPA subquery only positions in the `WHERE`, hence the Netbeans warning
2.`INNER JOIN` in JPA doesn't accept a subquery.
Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got the good query,

```
select pu from ProductUpdate pu where pu.id in (select MAX(pUd.id) from ProductUpdate pUd group by pUd.product.id) ORDER BY pu.id DESC.
```

I just use this post [JPA CriteriaBuilder for join in subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35148276/jpa-criteriabuilder-for-join-in-subquery) to perform my answer.

1. Using a JPA subquery only positions in the WHERE, hence the Netbeans warning
2. INNER JOIN in JPA doesn't accept a subquery.